# How do I disable the key part of a smart lock?

Tags: lock

I have a Schlage smart lock with a key pad and a keyed lock on the outside so the lock can be opened using the keypad or the key. I would like to disable the key function so it can only be opened with the key pad. I would’ve thought there was some kind of blank replacement for the key slot but I haven’t found anything. Any ideas?

Comment: You do know that you will need to use the key the day after, in the worst rain/lighting storm you ever had, when all the electronics are shot.

Comment: Some super glue or a structural adhesive forced into the key slot will do it.

Comment: I like the "structural adhesive" suggestion, @SteveSh. With enough of it in there, it will probably totally disable the lock.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. _Why_ do you want to disable the key-access portion of the lock? Did you lose a key/your ex hasn't returned it? Something else? I'd imagine you'll get better answers if you ask about the root problem instead of your assumed best-option answer...

Comment: @FreeMan - That's what I was thinking - KIS.  OP could always replace the cylinder if he wants key functionality back again.

Comment: Dip key in epoxy, insert into lock, allow to cure, hacksaw it off. Melt the entrance with a carbon arc or oxy-acetylene torch. Drive a suitably-sized nail into the keyway. There are many ways, and all involve cutting the lock off when the "smart" becomes "stupid" and won't work anymore, but you've smartly removed the backup key option. And cutting the lock off (or cutting a hole in the wall beside the door, or smashing a window, or hacking the "smart" function) is an option for whoever you think you're keeping out by removing the keyway - locks just keep honest people honest.

Comment: In answer to FreeMan, I want to make the lock unpickable. Newer versions of these locks don’t have a keyhole but they cost about $100 more than the originals. I’ve got these on more than one door so it doesn’t worry me if one of them goes out because of the power.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this, a locksmith may be able to rekey the cylinder to an "impossible" key, or (probably better) disconnect the tailpiece that lets the cylinder operate the latch mechanism.

Doing that may or may not interfere with maintaining the lock in the future, and the details will depend on the cylinder and lockset, so I personally don't want to get into discussion of it as a DIY project.

An alternative can sometimes be to swap out the cylinder for a higher security one, or to install modifications to make it more secure. On the other hand, a high security cylinder in a Grade 3 lockset is a bit of a joke unless you are more concerned about tamper detection than prevention. You may be looking at the wrong part of the system.

As others have said, you probably want to consider how you will enter the building if the lock loses power or otherwise  malfunctions.